# Facebook token to scrape through public pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook-token

Can someone explain to me how to get a facebook token to extract posts from public pages? I don't understand how to get it. I use the Graph API and select the user_posts feature.

I believe I then have to submit the app to Facebook, but I need a logo to do that?! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`user_profiles` is for User Profiles, not Pages. You need to use `manage_pages` and a Page Token for Pages you manage, or apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) with an App Token for pages you do not manage.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thank you. My question is regarding applying for a page public content access. How  do you apply? It is not clear to me and the Facebook instructions are useless

Comment: go to the review section of your app, there is a selection for it. you can provider a screencast of how you would like to use the access permission - for example, by using a page token for a page you manage just to show them how.